# Undefined Reference when using GCC and Windows.h in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, undefined-reference

I am trying to build this simple code in vscode, however the linker is reporting undefined references to library functions in windows.h. I am not sure why this is happening i usually use Visual Studio and did not had the need to externally link Windows library files but if i have to link them, how should i do it in vscode. Below is the code that i am trying to build:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <Windows.h>

  int main() {    

    /* hide console window */
    ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false);

    /* Calling GetDC with argument 0 retrieves the desktop's DC */
    HDC hDC_Desktop = GetDC(0);

    /* Draw a simple blue rectangle on the desktop */
    RECT rect = { 20, 20, 200, 200 };
    HBRUSH blueBrush=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,255));
    FillRect(hDC_Desktop, &rect, blueBrush);

    Sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

The following are the contents of launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

The contents of Tasks.json file are :

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "miDebuggerPath":"C:\\MinGW\\bin",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
        }
    ]
}
```

The output returned when building the code is:

```
Starting build...
Build finished with error:

C:\Users\Work\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnmSnMZ.o: In function `main':
c:/Users/Work/Desktop/so/code.cpp:14: undefined reference to `CreateSolidBrush@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Answer (score 0):

CreateSolidBrush function belongs to gdi32.lib, so you have to add it to your linker.
Hope it works :)

Comment: I know the library but how do i link it in vscode. I tried to link it by passing arguments to the linker in tasks.json file in the line  "args": [
    "-g",
    "${file}",
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "-l",
    "gdi32"
   ],  but the error persists.

Comment: I've never used VS Code for C++ but maybe something like: 
    "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "-L \\C:\\MinGW\\lib",
            "-l gdi32"
        ],. Using your current path of MinGW/lib

Comment: Its the same thing weather to include the path or not but its not working either way.